# Set a link to a pnp term

Tags: sharepoint-online, navigation, pnp-powershell, pnp, microsoft

i want to use poswershell to add a link to a sub term [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done this before by creating a CSV with two columns, "Terms" and "Link".  Then run the following powershell using PnP PowerShell cmdlets.

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url "$TenantURL" -UseWebLogin
$ctx = Get-PnPContext

$GroupName = "{name of the group where the terms live}"
$TermSet = "{name of the term set}"

$csv = Import-Csv -Path "C:\temp\{path to your csv file.csv}"
#Process entries in the CSV file
foreach($line in $csv){
    #Bind to Terms within the Term Set by using the values 
    #supplied in the "Terms" column of the CSV file
    $TermName = $line.Terms
    Write-Host $TermName
    $Link = $line.Link
    $Term = Get-PnPTerm -Identity "$TermName" -TermGroup "$GroupName" -TermSet "$TermSet" -Recursive

    $ctx.Load($Term)
    Invoke-PnPQuery 
    $Term.SetLocalCustomProperty("_Sys_Nav_SimpleLinkUrl", "$Link") 
    Invoke-PnPQuery  
}
```